# I am trying to find the specific character within a String Array. What must I end up using?

Tags: java, arrays

Below is the code.\ I imagine you use a for loop and then another but I cannot seem to make it work. I attempted research however most topics were too complex since I am a novice. I'm trying to find a way to get the fifth character out of each string within the variable. I'll use the information given to me so i can then solve the rest of my program. I have more to do

```
public static void main (String[]args)
{
     String[] decoder = {"Nexa2f5", "Z52Bizlm" , "Diskapr" , "emkem9sD", "LaWYrUs", "dAStn78L", "mPTuriye", "aaeeiuUu", "IL8Ctmpn"};
     int character = 4;
     for(int i=0; i<=decoder.length-1; i++)
     {

     }
}
```

I am trying to get the third and fourth characters of the odd numbered Strings. I am trying to put the letters into an array and decode the message. I am also trying to print the 5th character of all other words. I'm having issues commenting right and I've tried to reply a couple times but no dice.

Answer (score 0):

Within your for loop use the array indexing notation. For example, `String current = decoder[0]` results in `current` having the value `Nexa2f5`. Once you have the String Object (in my example, I named it `current`) you can use the `charAt()` method shown in the String class [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to get the 4th and 5th characters. If you need more help than that, read my comments then update your code and ask another question.